# What happens when a drawing is bigger than the canvas itself?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Suppose you have a 500x500 canvas and you draw an image(or line) which is bigger than the canvas itself

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,1000,1000);
```

What happens under the hood to the parts which don't get drawn as they are off-canvas? does it take more resources or the canvas engine simply ignores these off-canvas parts and barely take any performance hits, and is it just like drawing:

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,500,500);
```

I ask this as I making something a game with a grand-scale map and I want to know if I should pay attention to how I treat things which are temporary off-canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much time does drawing out of the canvas cost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848432/how-much-time-does-drawing-out-of-the-canvas-cost)

Comment: Didn't see it as suggested posts, but if his answer is trustworthy then you may close this one.